# RegEx - catch multiple items

Tags: php, regex

I have this textblock

```
[block]
     [item]catch me[/item]
     [item]catch me[/item]
     [item]catch me[/item]
[/block]
```

The number of items is variable. Now i want match every "catch me", preferably in an array. I have an expression, but this will only match the last item:

```
\[block\](?:\s*\[item\](.*?)\[/item\]\s*)+\[/block\]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks & regards,
Alex

Comment: Which language? `\[item\](.*?)\[/item\]` should match everything.

Comment: PHP. is it not possible in one regex statement?

Comment: The current regex is almost perfectly valid as far as I can tell... `\[block\](?:\s*\[item\](.*?)\[/item\]\s*)+?\[/block\]` (to fix the greediness).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm getting this right, you may need to do this in two steps, i.e. something like:

```
$items_regex = '/\[block\]((?:\s*\[item\].*?\[/item\]\s*)+?)\[/block\]/';
$item_regex = '/\[item\](.*?)\[/item\]/';

if (preg_match($items_regex, $str, $items)) {
   $items = end($items);
   if (preg_match_all($item_regex, $items, $match)) {
     $match = end($match);
     // do stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: thx, this looks good. what if, the number of blocks is variable too?

Comment: If you're meaning nested blocks, your best bet, imo, will be to convert blocks and items into xml tags, and to use an xml parser.

Comment: no, not nested, just block afer block. i guess `preg_match_all` for the block will do it, doesn't it?

Comment: oh, in that case yes. preg_match_all, and then loop through each one. The non-greedy modifier I added to your original regex should ensure that two subsequent blocks won't interfere with one another.

Comment: `$block_regex = '#\[block]((?:\s*\[item\].*?\[/item\]\s*)+?)\[/block]#is';
$items_regex = '#\[item\](.*?)\[/item\]#i';
if (preg_match_all($block_regex, $content, $block_items)) {
    foreach( $block_items[1] as $items ){
        if (preg_match_all($items_regex, $items, $item)) {
     $blocks[]=$item[1];
 }
    }
}` Thx a lot

Answer (score 3):

You don't show how you use the expression. You have to use [**`preg_match_all()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and you can also simplify your expression:

```
// assuming $str contains the text to match
preg_match_all("#\[item\](.*?)\[/item\]#", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [item]catch me[/item]
            [1] => [item]catch me[/item]
            [2] => [item]catch me[/item]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => catch me
            [1] => catch me
            [2] => catch me
        )

)
```

`$matches[1]` contains what you are looking for.

Comment: what is the `$str` variable for?

Comment: @Coding-Freak It is for the string you are processing ('[block]...').

Comment: @Coding-Freak: Added an explanation, it contains the text that should be matched.